# Load data from temp table to another temp table without any conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I'm trying to load data from Oracle server to SQL Server and storing data in Temp table. And copying the same data to another temp table with adding field names.

Using Union and then loading that data to csv file.

The thing is my first temp table gets all the data but the second temp table gets partial data even though there are no conditions applied.

Total rows are  320 K while im getting only 313 K rows.

I'm not getting any error that I can share with you. If you have come across this situation and able to solve this let me know.

Comment: Show your queries...

Comment: Is it some kind of script or direct query to db from some DBSM? I asked because have similar problem: DBSM limits query result by 200 rows, when query have no any limit (top) statements.

Comment: use SSIS. This is what its made to do

Comment: We need queries to help but I'm guessing it's in your join to your field name for the second temp table.

Comment: Hi Arthur, there are no joins in second temp table it's just inserting column name using Union and selecting all the data from first temp table

Comment: Shp, it is a direct query without any top limits

Comment: Nate its working in SSIS I'm just wondering why its not working in Sql.Server

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hard to know without your queries.

But, try use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`.

And, IMO, you should use Pentaho or a better way to load data, without use CSV+import.